# Can we use two popup in same touch level

Tags: android, popup

```
popupOne.onClick(view, 0, (int) viewHolder.parent.getY() + viewHolder.parent.getHeight());

PopupMenu popupM = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
popupM.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat_action_menu, popupM.getMenu());
popupM.show();
```

always can click popup menu item or dismiss popupM using outside click and then we can click popupOne. I need access both popup in same time. if user need click popupOne or popupM how available these two for user